# Code to connect to Sharepoint from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, sharepoint, pyspark, sharepoint-online, connector

I want to extract SharePoint List data using PySpark. I am not sure about the Sharepoint list data and storage. I want to read the SharePoint list data as a PySpark data frame.

I have tried Python Libraies:
Sharepy
Slum
Sharepoint and many others

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using pyspark from databricks, I am using a different approach.  I am using office 365 powerautomate flows to store the sharepoint lists in azure data storage as csv files.  These flows can be called from databricks via calling the http triggers of power automate in python or you can have power automate automatically update when data change occurs. The csv files can then be mounted as tables in sql analytics and used easily in databricks.  The benefit is microsoft offers and easy to use no code solution to exporting sharpoint to azure storage and it also handles all of the security nuances.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file/list that you want from Sharepoint first using one of the following packages, then you can use PySpark to ingest and process it.

- https://pypi.org/project/sharepoint/
- https://pypi.org/project/sharepy/

Here is a tutorial using Sharepy package: https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-get-data-from-sharepoint-with-python/

I hope it helps.